# I can't show actual format data from firebase database

Tags: android, json, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, I show some data from the Firebase realtime database. Mainly, it's showing some chemistry, physics and math formula. But, it doesn't show the actual format.

Below is an image of my Firebase realtime database.
[image]

In my app, it looks like this:
[image]

I want to look like this formula format:
[image]

How do I make it look like this actual formula format? Thank you.

Comment: sir this question link[ make equation in android ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428302/chemistry-formula-on-android) will help you what you want

Comment: Thank you for your response but i want to show too many formula and i am using firebase database.can i do this with firebase database

Comment: yes you can do it with data after retrieval thaat data from firebase through query and then display it on listview or recyclerview whereever you want.

Comment: Can you share any example or can you more explain?

Comment: see this library sir it shows the example also   https://github.com/RanaRanvijaySingh/EquationView

Comment: thank u for your valueble help sir.

Comment: ur welcome please up vote the answer if u an

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're storing the formulas as plaintext without any super- or subscript text. There's nothing built in to Firebase or Android to automatically detect formulas and then turn it into superscript/subscript, so you'll have to do that yourself by entering the text correctly.

For example, instead of:

```
"H2SO4"
```

Store it as:

```
"H₂SO₄"
```

Any rendering engine that takes Unicode should render this correctly, although there may be slight differences.

Comment: I was copy this formula and paste in my json file.how can i convert this?i can't store this original format.please explain this.thanks for response@Frank van Puffelen

Comment: How to get this into your database depends on how you got the original string in there in the first place. You should be able to copy/paste the value from my answer into the Firebase console for example, and that will store that exact text (including subscript numerals). If you added the current string in a different way, you'll have to describe that (in your question), so we we can help you find where you're going wrong.

Comment: You showed a screenshot, and I just looked up the unicode symbols for 2 and 4 subscripts. https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+subscript+2

Comment: Thank you, sir, I follow your advice